# php multiple include not working on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, dns

I've searched for an answer but found none. So, here it is: simple php page, before anything else I have:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
require_once("./include/inside_config.php");?>
```

On the same page, in the body, I have to include another page, a jquery thicker, like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center; color:#cccccc;">
    <?php include('thicker_it.php');?>
</div>
```

The last one returns error (Warning: include(thicker_it.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...) The fact is that the file exists, at that location (writing before "./" does not resolve the problem).

Note:

1. the DNS is forwarded to another server (I use another domain's server, the same provider GoDaddy).
2. the full-path solution does not work either (I changed the php.ini but the error persists).
   Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is going to sound a bit dumb but, have you double checked that thicker_it.php is in the same folder as the file that makes the includes (the top one)? Could you provide folder structure and in which folder is each included file?

Comment: You say this is a problem with _multiple_ include. If you remove the first include, does the problem with the second one go away?

Comment: Do you have a console, can you `ls -lh thicker_it.php` see the permissions of that file, can apache read it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can only be one of the following two:

a) Your file doesn't have read/execute premisions for the worker process owner.

b) The file is not where you think it is.

```
include(file.ext)
```

This is known as relative path and this is telling PHP that your file is located in the same directory as the script that is currently running, while:

```
include(/file.ext)
```

tells PHP that the file is in the root directory, this is known as absolute path.

The solution deppends on where your file is currently located, the relevant part of your directory structure could help us a bit more to help you.

Comment: whit great shame and blaming (50%) FileZilla I verified again the existence and the right for thicker_it.php. Now it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad its working now Cristian, working on a shared servers can get tricky sometimes. 


Reggards.